# What happened to Castle.Core.LifeStyleType in 1.3.0?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

This enum used to exist not too long ago. I am upgrading to Castle Core 1.3.0, and the enum is no more. What happened to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lives in Castle.Windsor.dll now. Did you used the enum outside of Windsor?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, it's also called LifestyleType instead of LifeStyleType.

Comment: So did you use it w/o Windsor?